# Add Remove List directives on Angular components

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, directive

I'm looking for a way to add/remove/list directives dynamically on Angular Components.
More concretely, I'm using the Angular Material's Drag & Drop feature and I want to dynamically enable/disable the `cdkDropList` directive.

Anyone has an amazing idea to achieve this ?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

just add cdkDragDisabled="variableTrueOrFalse"

answer found on github https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13651

and for the commit explanation : https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/282e5cdddaffc2d7b3821f848b7b046aba51e01d

Have a nice day !

Comment: I want to remove the `cdkDropList` directive to allow to drop the element wherever in the page

Comment: any luck with remove the cdkDropList?